# Laravel Eloquent - Get one Row

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This might be a simple question, but I cannot figure this out. I am trying to get a user by email using:

```
$user = User::whereEmail($email)->get();
```

But this is returning an array (of dimension 1) of $users. So If I want to get the name, I have to do `$user[0]['first_name']`.

I tried using `limit(1)` or `take(1)`, or even using `->toArray()` but there was no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 279, accepted):

**Simply use this:**

```
$user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();
```

Answer (score 32):

There are multiple ways.

1.
By using Model. Example:

```
User::where('column_name', 'value')->first();
```

2. 

Before you use this you must declare the DB facade in the controller
Simply put this line for that

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Now you can get a row using this

```
$getUserByEmail = DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->first();
```

or by this too

3.

```
$getUserByEmail = DB::select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?' , ['useremailaddress@email.com']);
```

This one returns an array with only one item in it and while the first one returns an object. Keep that in mind.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

Using Laravel Eloquent you can get one row using `first()` method,

it returns first row of table if `where()` condition is not found otherwise it gives the first matched row of given criteria.

**Syntax:**

```
Model::where('fieldname',$value)->first();
```

**Example:**

```
$user = User::where('email',$email)->first(); 
//OR
//$user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();
```

Answer (score 4):

**laravel 5.8**

If you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the `value()` method. This method will return the value of the column directly:

```
$first_name = DB::table('users')->where('email' ,'me@mail.com')->value('first_name');
```

check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results)

Answer (score 3):

Try with it

```
$color = \App\Color::take(1)->first();
```

Answer (score -3):

In your given code, simply use this:

```
$user = User::whereEmail($email)->first()->first_name
```

Answer (score -5):

```
$getUserByEmail = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $email"]);
```

Comment: This is unsafe!